# How to make a map with a contour plot overlay from latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: dictionary, location, wolfram-mathematica, visualization, contour

I have a csv file with longitude and latitude coordinates at various times and then another column that assigns a value from 1-10 for each of the location points. I want to create a contour map of each location and its value as a visualization. I was thinking of using mathematica but the very little programming experience I have is with python only.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my implementation for geographic maps in PHP at https://contourplot.codeplex.com. It uses a delaunay triangulation and a linear transformation along the edges of the triangles. It also uses 2 colors to show the difference between local and statewide z-values of any triangles and also the triangles and isolines maps nicely with the border (from the shapefile). Some shapes with extreme concavities, holes and islands can be a problem. Another algorithm is conrec from Paul Bourke. There is also the algorithm from indiemaps blogs but only for openlayers.